# MySQL Allows ODBC With Any Username

Tags: mysql, security, ms-access, odbc

I have a MySQL Community database on a remote server and I am trying to get Microsoft Access to read data from it. This data is sensitive. The problem is, MySQL doesn't care about the username that I give it in the .DSN file. It lets me read the ENTIRE database no matter what! How do I get it to actually check the username that I give it in the .DSN file?

edit: I'm not a DBA, I'm some intern who is over his head. Please don't assume that I know anything about anything  :)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect this is not an issue of MySQL "not checking" the username, but rather permissions which are too broad.

Start with `SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE Db = 'yourdb';` and ensure that only the desired permissions are set for your DB.

Comment: 0 rows returned. (I replaced yourdb with my db name)

Comment: Drop the where statement - there should really be rows there

Comment: Nothing was showing up because the user accounts all have % under 'Db'. There are rows for mysql.session and mysql.sys, plus the user accounts that I made, and the last line says "NULL" for each field. Could the null line be the issue?

Comment: You shouldn't be really editing permissions in that table, that's just a simple way to view them.

Comment: You need to lock down all your permissions and only open them back up to specific resources where needed. This will solve your problem, I suspect

Comment: Additionally, another route to check: Have you tried connecting from outside access? It could be possible access is doing something else.

Comment: How could I test ODBC without Access?

Comment: The only permissions are for users who should have full access to everything on the server, plus mysql.session and mysql.sys. What do you mean by lock down my permissions?

Comment: You could just connect directly, not using ODBC. Use some other MySQL client, like MySQL workbench, DBeaver, or even just the command line tool, 'mysql'. ODBC is just one MySQL client.

Comment: I tried logging in on the command line (mysql -u fakeuser -p). This worked and after I logged in I could select anything from any database. What would cause this? There isn't a "fakeuser" in mysql.users.

Comment: I figured it out... While I was poking around with the server I got an error informing me that -skip-grant-tables was enabled. This setting was not enabled. But trying "flush privileges;" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The server thought that it was started with -skip-grant-tables, which allows anyone to login as any user with any password. This option wasn't even enabled, but I tried running "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" and that solved the problem.