# MySQL database getting connected with any username and password

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

We have a website running on an custom Ubuntu server managed and hosted by the client himself, since last two days the website database is getting hacked and someone deletes all the db tables from the database.

Upon checking the Db connection I come to know that database is getting connected with any username and password, is there any configuration issue in mysql? I am not able to find anything on google or stackoverflow.

Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

**EDIT:** I checked mysql users table and there are three users in the table as listed below,

1. root
2. mysql.sys
3. mysql.session

Comment: *database is getting connected with any username and password* Really `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows that all connections have different usernames and hosts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Allows ODBC With Any Username](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199752/mysql-allows-odbc-with-any-username)

Comment: @Akina, yes it was allowing login with any username and password.. as per suggested by @Barmar, it was due to option `--skip-grant-tables`.. after turning it off it works normally.. To turn off I ran `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` command.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As per suggested by [Mr. Barmar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/123809/barmar) it was causing due to `--skip-grant-tables` in MySQL.

To disable this option just run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` command in your MySQL CLI and this will solve the issue.